# CSS: Can't align Button and Input together

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html), there is an interesting way to append a button right next to the input.

Just an example for illustration:

```
<div class="input-append">
<input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
<button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>
```

In my case I am trying to utilize this concept but the button is slightly bigger (by one pixel) I can't figure out what is causing this.

[image]

I have created a fiddle, I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/FkEnm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something else in your CSS causing this issue. 
You can fix this issue by overwriting your css. Make `line-height` from 20px to 19px on `.btn` class:

```
.btn { line-height: 19px }
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FkEnm/3/)

Comment: I really don't have any custom css here. So I don't understand why this happening.  Same problem is in this fiddle, this time the text field is bigger than the button and your trick doesn't help here. :( http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/GcjkC/2/

Comment: weird, could be a Firefox problem. :(

Comment: Had a quick look in Firefox and adding height: 30px seems to fix the issue in both browsers.

Comment: @Houman Buttons and input take on inherited styles differently. A `button` generally needs its own declaration for font-family, font-size etc. So if you have globals set up they won't make it to your buttons.